# subquery uses ungrouped column "psi.product_id" from outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

I have the following model:

[image: Model]

For every stock item, I'd like to know the the total ordered amount. In my model, every product is linked to one or many stock items together with an amount. And every order item is linked to a product, also with an amount.

Example: The product is "Screws Box", and it's linked to 50x stock item "Screw". A customer placed an order with 3x "Screws Box". That leads to a total of 150 ordered screws.

The query I built is the following:

```
SELECT
  stock_item.id,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM("amount"),
      (
        SELECT SUM("amount")
        FROM order_item AS item
        WHERE item.product_id = psi.product_id
      ) AS "item_amount"
    FROM product_productstockitem AS psi
    WHERE psi.stock_item_id = stock_item.id
  ) AS "product_amount"
FROM stock_stockitem AS stock_item
;
```

PostgreSQL tells me this:

```
ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "psi.product_id" from outer query
LINE 10:         WHERE item.product_id = psi.product_id
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want to join the tables together and aggregate:

```
select s.id,
       sum(psi.amount * oi.amount)
from stock_stockitem s left join
     product_productstockitem psi
     on psi.stock_item_id = stock_item.id left join
     order_item oi
     on oi.product_id = psi.product_id
group by s.id
```